# Need Faster way to remove leading Zero from Dates in Excel Output

Tags: excel, date

We have an internal software that exports data reports to Excel, and several of the columns contain dates in the MM/DD/YYYY format. I have a spreadsheet setup where I will copy these exported reports over to, and then I have formulas already setup to look for these dates. The problem currently is that all dates in months 1-9 come in like this: 01/22/2017.
[image]

The formulas do not recognize them until I activate each and every cell, and hit enter, and then it re-formats to: 1/22/2017 and then everything works. Currently I am having to go cell by cell and activate, and hit enter. Simply selecting all of the cells, and changing the formatting to a Date hasn't worked. Is there a faster way around this? I'm open to VBA if it works, however I'm wondering if there is a simpler method I'm missing, or simply a way to get my formulas to recognize the original date formatting.

EDIT:
The data is exported from a SQL database. The formulas that need to reference are using <= in reference to week start dates on another sheet. I initially tried having those match this formatting, but because the dates come as General, math operators don't work at that point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the date column and then click Data > Text to Columns
Next, Next, then select Date 'MDY'

then you should be able to do this using a number format of `m/dd/yyyy` or `m/d/yyyy` if you don't want a leading zero in the days as well

Answer (score 1):

select the range and run:

```
selection.value = selection.value
```

(for some cases this does not work)... in such moments this should do:

```
selection.value = evaluate("INDEX(" & selection.address & "+0,)")
```

just keep in mind that there **may** be a need of changing the formatting of the cell...

Answer (score 0):

This also can be done in a formula, without having to go through menu options, thus making it more automatic. Use TEXT and command and format the date exactly how you want. Leaving off leading zeros on the month or day is as simple as including just one character for them instead of two:

```
=TEXT(date-field,"M/D/YYYY")
```

instead of

```
=TEXT(date-field,"MM/DD/YYYY")
```